# Prescriptive analysis using random forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

Here is a general question in machine learning:

Suppose I have a random forest to predict a failure event in an experiment, the variables consist of both categorical(e.g. type of equipment) and continuous types (time of exposure/amount of reactant).

When it comes to make recommendations to the user (such that he is not going to blow up things), how should I make specific prescriptions, for example use equipment A and add X amount of chemical B?

I was thinking about doing a grid search by building a lattice of potential solutions, and find the optima. But this is expensive and has no guarantee to always return the best solution.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but please...if this is actually a safety critical system it has to be absolutely airtight. If you're asking for random advice on the internet, this raises serious questions. People can die or be injured in life changing ways when these systems fail. You don't want that on your conscience.

Comment: That's true. It should be rigorously correct in any critical situation. This question is just for curiosity in case something is so uncertain that chances have to be taken.

Answer (score 1):

For causal inference you want guarantees that your estimates are unbiased.  [This paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/wager14a/wager14a.pdf) gives a procedure for generating confidence intervals for random forests, while [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04342) proves that they are consistent and asymptotically normal.  Both papers however deal with regression forests, and not classification forests.  It seems like a thoroughly possible extension, but I'm not aware that it has yet been studied in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could also run straightforward classification and regression trees (CART) analysis using its one-step approach.  CART results will inform you which equipment is associated more with accidents, and what level of A is the cutpoint or threshold value above(below) which accidents are mostly seen.  I typically use RF to obtain importance scores for features, and obtain a value of class prediction accuracy which is less overfitted.

Comment: That is correct in the case that those variables have independent contribution to the result. What if there is a latent association that equipment A should always be combined chemical B for some reason? I am interested if individual feature importance is sufficient in this case.

Comment: For latent dimensions, you'd have to use either artificial neural networks (ANN), or path analysis via LISREL, STATA, etc.